# How to load https:// websites on click of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have made a Chrome Extension for webpage translation but when I load a `https://` based website and click on the chrome extension, it shows the shield icon and asks to click on to *load unsafe script*. But what I want is, when I click on chrome extension it should automatically load that page and start the translating process, I don't want that shield message to intervene between clicking on chrome extension and my servlet code. I have read about a command `--allow-running-insecure-content` and I don't know how to use it in my java code to automatically load that website.

I have not done it yet because I am not sure that this is write solution or not and it is also related to security so I didn't want to take risk with my computer without any proper guidance about it. Kindly help me. How to automatically load the scripts without clicking on that shield button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you.

Comment: Kindly help me, if anybody know about this

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the `http:` or `https:` and use just `//`

`http://path.to.image` => `//path.to.image`

Comment: it's not in my hand sir. See, i will open a website and click on the chrome extension. now, how will i remove remove http:// or https://.